# jQuery animate nav bar , can't animate

Tags: jquery

OK so I'm a little bit confused, I tried anything but stil cant animate my links background-color, or even simple alert, help me solve the prob :

```
/* jQuery */

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#menu a").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow");

    });


});
```

HTML :

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.xn----2hckboeejufb0a1k.com/">One</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.xn----2hckboeejufb0a1k.com/">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.xn----2hckboeejufb0a1k.com/">Three</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works just fine... see: http://jsfiddle.net/georeith/MhmAm/

The `left` property will have no effect unless the `a` elements have a non-static position property.

You also can't animate the property `background-colour` without a plugin. See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Else ensure you are correctly loading the jQuery library and check the console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the opacity bro.

$(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
            left: '-=50',
            height: 'toggle'
          }, 'slow');

Comment: WHat has opacity got to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#menu a").mouseover(function () {
        changeColor($(this),["olive","red","blue","white"]);
    });
    function changeColor(component,colors){
        var firstColor = colors[0];
        for(var i in colors){
            component.animate({ backgroundColor: colors[i]}, 'slow' , function(){
                if(colors.length < (i + 1)){
                    component.animate({ backgroundColor: colors[i + 1]},'slow',function(){
                        component.animate({ backgroundColor: firstColor}, 'slow');
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```